# Choosing a level editor of a 2d platformer

Tags: java, box2d, libgdx

I'm working with a small team on a 2D platformer game in Java (LibGDX) that uses Box2D for physics.
Our team is looking for a tool to make the levels (that we will be able to integrate with the Box2D physics, and the graphics). 
We want a tool that is able to work with polygons (not with tiles), and that can be used from Linux (and preferably Open Source).
Any suggestions ?

(Of-course I can write a little level-editor specific to our game, and if this is the case please write, but I would like to avoid that if there is another way )

Comment: [Tiled](http://www.mapeditor.org/) is available for Linux and can work with polygons. I'm not sure of the extent to which it can be integrated with Box2D but you could give it a shot.

Comment: There are a number of 2D tile editors available for free. The two most commonly talked about editors which support Java are [Mappy](http://www.tilemap.co.uk/mappy.php), and Tiled. Each of these editors supports Box2D integration and are able to run on Linux. However Mappy is only usable under Wine on Linux. A step by step guide on how to use Wine for Linux can be found [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Use-Wine-on-Linux).